# Transaction reverting while deploying contract with remix

Tags: remix, contract-debugging, solidity-0.8.x

I'm trying to deploy [this contract](https://github.com/Kactus83/CaritaCoin/blob/main/Contracts/CaritaCoinOneContract.sol) on remix but i get an VM error and the transaction is reverting. Error is "the called function should be payable if you send value".

At the beginning I used to deploy all the contracts separately and set variables manually. Then I wanted to integrate in the coin's constructor the annex contracts and the error appeared.

I'm trying to debug it but i'm totally lost.

Comment: If it fails at deployment then the constructor is reverting.

Comment: After a closer look it would seem that the constructors are Ok. The problem seems to come from tu "charityBuyForLiquidity" function.

Initially, the function was only available on the presales contract. I tried to put it on the token itself but it seems to cause trouble.

I think i have done a mistake when forwarding the initial value of the call (on the token contract) to the presale contract .. anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved!

Seems to be a remix bug or problem with my browser's cache. One day without working on the project and it's now deploying fines without changing the code.

I'm still open to any comments on the code if anyone is interested!